# When we render react Components from an iterable using Array.prototype.map() how is the index generated, and how does react uses it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to know, if the content of the iterating object has any effect on the index being generated, for example if the iterating objects have identical key values, will it generate identical indices or will the key prop accepted will get affected ?

example i was using this array:

```
[
  {id: 1, bank: "HDFC", account:"345345"},
  {id: 1, bank: "Stabdard_Chartered", account:"678567"},
]
```

I want to know, if the index argument of map() has any dependency on the first / item argument. As I observed so recently. All the items in the array was having the same id as 1 and the keys were automatically converted to .$1 for some reason, however when we changed id to unique values, it started working as expected

Comment: I want to know, if the index argument of map() has any dependency on the first / item argument. As I observed so recently. All the items in the array was having the same id as 1 and the keys were automatically converted to .$1 for some reason, however when we changed id to unique values, it started working as expected

Answer (score 1):

The key isn't generated automaticly you need to add your own key (see example), react uses the key to track which element needs to be updated on every rerender.

```
{array.map((item) => {
    return <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
})
```

You may also use the `index` of the `map` as your key, though many advise against it, the index is the 2nd (optional) argument passed to the map like this

```
{array.map((item, index) => {
    return <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
})
```

Comment: I want to know, if the index argument of `map()` has any dependency on the first / item argument. As I observed so recently. All the items in the array was having the same `id` as 1 and the keys were automatically converted to `.$1` for some reason, however when we changed `id` to unique values, it started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If jus just want a simple key the second argument of map is a index you could use it as a key

```
objects.map(objs,index) => { return <Obj key={index} /> }
```

Comment: I want to know, if the index argument of map() has any dependency on the first / item argument. As I observed so recently. All the items in the array was having the same id as 1 and the keys were automatically converted to .$1 for some reason, however when we changed id to unique values, it started working as expected

Comment: No the index argument has no dependency on the item. The index argument is is a new number for every new item. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map